# Modify Laravel Eloquent Relations after Models have been retrieved

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

A collection of models and their necessary relations (eager loaded) have been retrieved from the DB. When further processing the results, it becomes necessary to inverse some of the relationships. In order to save resources, no additional relations should be loaded from the DB.

The initial query looks the following:

```
$resource = Model_A::with([
  'Model_B',
  'Model_C'
])->paginate(25);
```

The initial results look the following:

```
Collection {
  #items: array:3 [
    0 => Model_A {
      ...
      #relations: array:2 [
        "Relation_Model_B" => Model_B { ... },
        "Relation_Model_C" => Model_C { ... }
      ...
    },
    1 => Model_A {
      ...
      #relations: array:2 [
        "Relation_Model_B" => Model_B { ... },
        "Relation_Model_C" => Model_C { ... }
      ...
    },
    2 => Model_A {
      ...
      #relations: array:2 [
        "Relation_Model_B" => Model_B { ... },
        "Relation_Model_C" => Model_C { ... }
      ...
    }
  ]
};
```

After transformation the result should look the following:

```
Collection {
  #items: array:2 [
    0 => Model_B {
      ...
      #relations: array:1 [
        "Relation_Model_A" => array:3 [
           0 => Model_A { ... },
           1 => Model_A { ... },
           1 => Model_A { ... }
         ]
      ]
      ...
    },
    1 => Model_C {
      ...
      #relations: array:1 [
        "Relation_Model_A" => array:3 [
           0 => Model_A { ... },
           1 => Model_A { ... },
           1 => Model_A { ... }
         ]
      ]
      ...
    }
  ]
};
```

I already looked into the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` and `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` Classes, but my PHP and Laravel knowledge is not strong enough yet to figure it out on my own.

Thank you for your support! This is much appreciated!

Comment: Could you include your query logic? I mean, how are you getting your models.

Comment: Also, how much do you expect to get when doing this query (in order to advise you to do a Collection transformation or modify the query itself)

Comment: I added the Eloquent Query. The initial results are used to prepare a requested API resources, should then be "transformed" (cloning child as parent with parent as child) in order to add some finale information to the API resource prior to sending the response.